# How to write a greentext module using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am writing a simple forum for my website using JQuery and instead of using `[quote][/quote]` to do quotations I want to use `>` for greentext like on 4chan. So if you have a post like

```
"This is a normal line
>this is a quotation"
```

"this is a quotation" would be green, because there is a `>` on a new line, and the text would be green until there's a whole new line (enter is pressed).

How can I write a jQuery module to implement greentext, where the class of anything following `>` on a new line is `color: green` until the next new line?

What I'm specifically struggling with is how to modify the class of text inside a `<p>` based on detecting a `>`

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to create your own? There are lots of libraries to interpret/render markdown already, such as [in this example](https://gist.github.com/josephdicdican/b1aa514e17eb555c99441b80bab32233), and the styling of each can easily be amended to your needs using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure possible... Assuming the criteria is having the `>` character as the very first character of a text string inside a `<p>`.

```js
$("p").each(function(){
  // If there is a > at position 0 in a <p>
  if($(this).text().indexOf(">")==0){
    // Remove the > character and add a CSS class
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1)).addClass("quote")
  }
})
```

```css
p.quote{
  color: green;
  /* feel free to add more */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Normal string</p>
<p>>Quotation</p>
```